# Read txt file using Pandas: space delimiter and column position

Tags: python, pandas, io

Here is a subset of the txt file I am trying to read into a pandas DataFrame:

```
ACW00011604  17.1167  -61.7833   10.1    ST JOHNS COOLIDGE FLD                       
ACW00011647  17.1333  -61.7833   19.2    ST JOHNS                                    
AE000041196  25.3330   55.5170   34.0    SHARJAH INTER. AIRP            GSN     41196
AEM00041194  25.2550   55.3640   10.4    DUBAI INTL                             41194
AEM00041217  24.4330   54.6510   26.8    ABU DHABI INTL                         41217
```

As you can tell it uses space as the delimiter, and also has missing values and various length for each field. The schema is like this:

```
Variable   Columns   Type

ID            1-11   Character
LATITUDE     13-20   Real
LONGITUDE    22-30   Real
ELEVATION    32-37   Real
STATE        39-40   Character
NAME         42-71   Character
GSN FLAG     73-75   Character
HCN/CRN FLAG 77-79   Character
WMO ID       81-85   Character
```

What is the best way to do this?

Comment: Do you know about `pd.read_fwf()`?

Comment: now I do! Thank you